# new/delete "override" vs. "overload"

Tags: c++, overloading, new-operator, overriding, delete-operator

I always thought...

- *overriding* means reimplementing a function (same signature) in a base class whereas
- *overloading* means implementing a function with same name but different signature

... and got confused because sometimes people just don't care about the difference.

Concerning new/delete: Are they overloaded or overridden?

An idea:

- implementing new/delete operator in a Class = overload
- reimplementing global new/delete = override

Any corrections/suggestions/objections?
And feel free to tag the question "hairsplitting"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the global `operator new` and `operator delete`, it's actually neither overloading nor overriding.  A program is permitted to *replace* the default, implementation-provided definitions with its own definitions.  The C++ standard says (§3.7.3/2):

> The library provides default definitions for the global allocation and deallocation functions. Some global allocation and deallocation functions are replaceable (18.4.1). A C++ program shall provide at most one definition of a replaceable allocation or deallocation function. Any such function definition replaces the default version provided in the library (17.4.3.4).

For a class-specific `operator new` or `operator delete`, the operators are *overloaded*.

Comment: So overloading and overriding are equally wrong here, which explains the 50-50 distribution in usage :-)

Comment: James: While I think what your wrote is right, you can still _overload_ both global operators with ones taking additional (or different) arguments. In fact, the std lib comes with at least to overloads: one placement new and the `nothrow` variant.

Comment: @sbi:  Right.  Well, the global operators are overloaded, and each of the overloads can be replaced.  @spc-mrn:  Yes, effectively.